# Calculate mean and concatenate string with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, logic

Mostly can be done, just want to know why this didn't work.

#### Task

```js
function mean(list) {
  var letters = [];
  var numbers = 0;
  for (var listval in list) {
    console.log(Number(list[listval]))
    if (typeof(Number(list[listval])) === typeof 0) {
      numbers += Number(list[listval]);
    } else {
      letters.push(list[listval]);
    }
  };
  console.log(letters);
  console.log(numbers);
}

mean(['u', '6', 'd', '1', 'i', 'w', '6', 's', 't', '4', 'a', '6', 'g', '1', '2', 'w', '8', 'o', '2', '0']);
```

#### Logic

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.
I wanted my program to go through every element in the list and check using the **Number** function whether or not it could be converted into an integer.
if it could be converted into an integer, convert to integer and add to *numbers* variable, otherwise do nothing to the element and push to the *letters* array.

This doesn't work at all. Why?

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if it works?

Comment: I get 36 as output and all the list.

Comment: This is the key: `if (parseInt(list[listval]) == list[listval]) {`

Comment: Dude, you still there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is the `for ... in` loop, which converts every index to `string` and screws it up. You need to really try with `for` loop here:

```js
function mean(list) {
  var letters = [];
  var numbers = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var listval = i;
    console.log(parseInt(list[listval]));
    if (parseInt(list[listval]) == list[listval]) {
      numbers += parseInt(list[listval]);
    } else {
      letters.push(list[listval]);
    }
  };
  console.log(letters);
  console.log(numbers);
}

mean(['u', '6', 'd', '1', 'i', 'w', '6', 's', 't', '4', 'a', '6', 'g', '1', '2', 'w', '8', 'o', '2', '0']);
```

Also, the condition is always truthy, as both the sides give you `Number` as `NaN` is Number. So you need to check with `NaN`.

**Output**

[image: preview]